# Angular Chart.js fill= false not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a line chart using angular-chart:  http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/
, and Im trying to remove the fill below the lines.

```
     <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="ctrl.data"
            chart-colors="colors"
            chart-labels="ctrl.labels" chart-series="ctrl.series" chart-options="ctrl.options"
            chart-dataset-override="ctrl.datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
    </canvas>
```

This are my option. Ive tried with fill:false and dataFill:false

```
  vm.options = {
          type:'line',
          datasetFill:false,
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              type:"time",
              time:{
                min: vm.initialTime,
                max: vm.endTime
              },
              position: 'bottom'
            }]
          }
        };
```

Ive also tried adding the colors option like this:

```
$scope.colors = [{
        backgroundColor : '#0062ff',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#0062ff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#0062ff',
        borderColor: '#0062ff',
        pointBorderColor: '#0062ff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: '#0062ff',
        fill: false /* this option hide background-color */
    }, '#00ADF9', '#FDB45C', '#46BFBD'];
```

and got no results.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure ctrl.options is equal to vm.options ? Got it working myself the same way many times.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the error. The problem was with the setting of the series variable.
series was declared as:

```
ctrl.series = [1,2,3]
```

it fixed when changed to this:

```
ctrl.series = [[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using ng4-charts with chart.js, and I found that setting the fill: false in the colors worked for me. I am not using datasets, but just an array of data and was trying to set fill in options (which seemed correct from the help). Adding fill: false to my chartColors removed the fill.

```
chartColors = [
{
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  borderColor: '#0062ff',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(103, 58, 183)',
  pointBorderColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(103, 58, 183, .8)',
  fill: false
},
// ...colors for additional data sets
];
```

My chart use:

```
<canvas 
  baseChart
  [chartType]="'line'"
  [data]="chartData"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  [labels]="chartLabels"
  [colors]="chartColors"
  [legend]="false"
></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use transparent fill: "rgba(220,220,220,0)"

Comment: Maybe you use "colours" not "colors"?

Comment: No I used exactly the same code as in the original question just changing the  `fill:false ` to  `fill:"rgba(220,220,220,0)" `

Answer (score 0):

`options = {elements:{ line: {fill:false}}}` works for me